# Cannot echo query result--query is obviously correct? Very simple PHP

Tags: php, mysql

So I am attempting to create an HTML drop-down list.  The list is fine--and it shows all of my desired options from a MySQL query of it's own; however my next step was to set the default value (which is the current landlord) for the tenant.

Now, I am able to successfully, but only with the landlords key (which is in a separate table).  I have a second query that looks up the landlord's name based on the key, and I cannot even get it to echo out a response.  I must assume the query is bad--but after looking at the same lines of code the entire morning, I believe I can confidently say it is not.  I am hoping a second set of eyes will see something I do not.

**Getting the current landlord for the tenant**:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT data_txt FROM field_data WHERE itemid = $uid AND fieldid = 16");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$ll1 = $row[0];
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT info FROM landlords WHERE key = $ll1 LIMIT 1");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$ll1_name = $row[0]
```

**Setting the default value in the Dropdown-list**:

I don't believe the problem lies here, since I cannot do anything as simple as echo the variable $ll1_name; but I feel it's worth including.

```
<td>

<?php echo "$ll1"; ?><br>

<?php echo "$ll1_name"; ?><br>

<select name=ll1>

<option value="<?php echo "$ll1"; ?>"> <?php echo "$ll1_name"; ?></option>
<?php
while ($curLandlord = mysql_fetch_array($landlordRows)){
?>
<option value="<?php echo "$curLandlord[0]"; ?>"> <?php echo "$curLandlord[1]"; ?></option>

<?php
}
?>


</select>
</td>
```

Also, I am well aware that this library is depreciated and my fields are not sanitized, etc.  I am just making this as simple as possible, and then implementing that after I have a working model.  The fewer variables, the better.

The following is an example of the table data:

**Landlords**

key, info, id (auto increment)

```
-*key*: ll1_07
-*info*: John Doe
-*id*: 77
```

**field_data**
id, fieldid, data_txt, itemid

```
-*id*: 1234 (auto increment)
-*fieldid*: 18 (each fieldid corresponds to a field name in another table.  18 is landlord)
-*data_txt*: ll1_77
-*itemid*: 33 (tenants unique ID)
```

Comment: post table with some data

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not "correct". You have an sql injection vulnerability. Just because your `$ll1` value came out of the DB doesn't mean it's safe to REUSE in another query. You're doing the equivalent of

```
SELECT info FROM landlords WHERE key = foo LIMIT 1
                                       ^^^---unknown/illegal field name
```

instead of

```
SELECT info FROM landlords WHERE key = 'foo' LIMIT 1
                                       ^^^^^--string literal
```

If you had even BASIC error handling on your query calls, you'd have been informed of this:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT [..snip..]") or die(mysql_error());
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Never **EVER** assume success on a query. Even if the sql is 100% syntactically correct, there's a near infinite number of reasons for it to STILL fail (biggest one: missing foreign key).

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified; but I'd already tried that.  That does not work either.  I just posted the question while trying a number of different combinations--perhaps I should have double checked to make sure my query was correct before hand!  But regardless, that does not work either... oddly!

Comment: well, in your sample data, you have `data_txt=ll1_77`, and `key=ll1_07`. unless that's a typo, that'd also be why you're not getting anything.

Comment: No, that was an error on my part.  I was just throwing random data into the "table" to give you an example of the layout.  I should have made sure it was consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and see what the response is:

```
$sql = "
    SELECT
        fd.data_text,
        l.info
    FROM
        field_data fd
    JOIN
        landlords l
        ON fd.data_text = l.key
    WHERE
        fd.itemid = $uid
        AND fd.fieldid = 16
    LIMIT 1";

$rs = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($rs);

var_dump($row);
```

That should tell you if you are getting any data back.